# mongodb: how to populate a single nested subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am writing a node.js application using mongodb and mongoose.  I seems to be having an issue in understanding how to query "single nested subdocuments".  If I have an example like the following:

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  // Single nested subdocuments. Caveat: single nested subdocs only work
  // in mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

from the mongoose documentation, how do I populate the child subdocument for a single nested scenario?  I tried to use the ".populate("child").exec..." but the child object returns null even though I can find if I run db.child.find() from the mongo command line.  Now I saw in the documentation, where you have to call "parent.children.id(_id)" but in this case I will not know the _id ahead of time.

Update: I removed the populate and it appears to be working now.

Comment: The data is "embedded" so there is nothing to "populate" since it's already there. Population refers to retrieving "referenced" data from other collections. More or less superseded by `$lookup` for modern MongoDB releases. But also not needed here at all.

Comment: Can you show me an example from the code above to demonstrate how this should work?

Comment: What example? "embedded" means it's "already there". Simply retrieve the document. Job done. Do you have something actually stored? What is the question? What have you done? What do you still not understand?

Comment: So, I assume you are saying that it should just populate without calling populate method.  If that is the case, I tried that as well and still received null for child.

Comment: You need to show what you are actually doing and what you expect. This has nothing to do with "population" based on the presented schema. The very act of calling `.populate()` is likely messing up your results. Show how you save your data and show how you are trying to retrieve it. Basically read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to present your case as described there. Then we know how to address your concerns. Or you figure it out yourself in following that process.

Answer (score 0):

You are already storing the child document as embedded one inside the parent document, so there is no need to populate. Populate is for those cases where you are storing a reference to other document which you want to be populated while running the query. An example for such case would be :

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
var childModel = mongoose.model("child", childSchema);

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // Array of subdocuments
  children: [childSchema],
  child: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'child'
  }
});
```

Now if you try to populate `child` while querying `parent`, it should work.